# Symfony - Security strategy unanimous show voters involved

Tags: security, symfony, acl, firewall

I'm trying to use ACLs, and as suggested I switched the security strategy to `unanimous`.

Since then, several URLs don't authorize my user to access anymore.
However it should according to my firewall configuration (I'm able to control this with default strategy).

I understand that unanimous strategy denies access if at least one voter doesn't grant.

So the question is:

For a given request in case of denied access,
how to know which are the involved voters in order to know which one is denying access ?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue since switching **access_decision_manager** strategy to **unanimous**. Since Symfony 2.4, expressions are built in by default, and I used this to solve the issue.

For my access control to use multiple roles I had:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_MANAGER, ROLE_EDITOR] }
```

After changing to:

```
access_control:
       - { path: ^/, allow_if: "has_role('ROLE_ADMIN') or has_role('ROLE_MANAGER') or has_role('ROLE_EDITOR')" }
```

It solved the unanimous issue, hope it helps you or anyone out there.

Comment: After reading this solution suddenly I feel a lot deeper understanding about voters. :D Ty. Saved me some time.

Answer (score 0):

I were not able to find a way to see the involved voters in case of denied access but:

I finally found what was denied: With unanimous strategy, when your security/access_control defines routes against multiple roles, your user must be granted to all to have access. It is logical actually...

That does not answer to the question but I think that is good to keep in mind when using unanimous security strategy.

Answer (score 0):

For your question: how to know which are the involved voters in order to know which one is denying access ?

The answer: You should search for the tag name "security.voter" in your services.
All security voters are registered that way.
All these voters are always used.

For the part of: For a given request in case of denied access,

The answer:

As each request has a different approach to the security voters, based on a token, it is almost  impossible to see which voter denied you access without debugging. Use a tool like Xdebug to see the flow of the voters if you really want to know.

You could make a Unit Test for your code to see if it is accessible at the time of a certain request though.